# E492: Not an editor command: Pluginstall

Tags: vim

so im trying to install some plugins for vim but some errors pop up "E492: Not an editor command: Pluginstall" i downloaded Vundle and i think i entered other thing correctly

```
syntax on


set nocompatible          
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

set noerrorbells
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set incsearch

set colorcolumn=80
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey

call vundle#begin()

Plug 'gmarik/vundle'
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
plug 'jremmen/vim-ripgrep'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'vim-utils/vim-man'
Plug 'git@github.com:kien/ctrlp.vim.git'
Plug 'git@github.com:Valloric/YouCompleteMe.git'
Plug 'mbill/undotree' 

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
```

and source % works fine but when i type :PluginInstall the error pop up

Comment: Visit: `https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/wiki/tips#automatic-installation`. Place the code in your .vimrc before `plug#begin()` call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Vundle the [commands are `Plugin` and `PluginInstall`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#quick-start).

Commands `Plug` and `PlugInstall` are for [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#usage).

Comment: after i change plug to plugin and  enterer PlugInstall this message pop up "Error detected while processing function vundle#installer#new: " and "no bubdles were selected" for operation btw thx for helping

Comment: @Jas0n `PlugInstall` -> `PluginInstall`